# Ubuntu 16.04 WiFi not working | Realtek RTL8723DE

Tags: networking, realtek

I cannot connect to WiFi in Ubuntu 16.04 on an HP 15.6 Notebook. I have found lots of answers to this that would probably help. However, I cannot use anything that involves the internet such as GIT because there is no wifi. I cannot use Ethernet because I don't have an Ethernet port in my office. Please help me.

Answer (score 0):

Currently it only works with kernel version 4.14

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:teejee2008/ppa

sudo apt-get update

sudo apt-get install ukuu
```

Install version 4.14

[image]

Restart.

Make sure v4.14 is Running

```
git clone https://github.com/smlinux/rtl8723de.git -b 4.11-up
dkms add ./rtl8723de
dkms install rtl8723de/5.1.1.8_21285.20171026_COEX20170111-1414
depmod -a
reboot
```

Now wifi should appear.